# Conditional expectation with respect to several independent variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ be random variables such that $X_1 \perp X_i$ for $i \in \left\{{2,3,4}\right\}$. It could be say that $\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_2, X_3, X_4]=\mathbb{E}[X_1]$? I need to find $\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2X_3X_4]$ assuming that every variable $X_i$ is normal with mean $0$. By Isselis's theorem, $\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2X_3X_4]=0$, but I'm trying to find this value without using Isseli's theorem.

Comment: by $\perp$ you mean independent, don't you?

Comment: Right: with $\perp$, I mean independent.